# How to determine Big O time complexity of the following recursion: f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-3) + c

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

How can I solve this recursion :
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-3) + c.
where c is constant
f(1)=1

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Welcome to SO, for such type of questions, please post it [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

Answer (score 0):

We explicitly solve for the function. First, add `c` to both sides to get

`f(n) + c = (f(n - 1) + c) + (f(n - 3) + c)`

Define `g(n) = f(n) + c`. Then the recurrence for `g` is

`g(n) = g(n - 1) + g(n - 3)`

Note that the set of solutions to this equation forms a vector space of dimension 3, since `g` is determined by `g(0), g(1), g(2)`. So it suffices to find 3 basis elements.

We try an Ansatz of `g(n) = k^n` for `k` nonzero. For such an Ansatz, we see that

`k^n = k^(n - 1) + k^(n - 3)`

In other words, we see that

`k^3 = k^2 + 1`

This equation has no rational roots, so its roots will be a bit nasty. It turns out that there are three roots, one real and two complex. The roots are approximately

`x = 1.47`
`x = -0.233 +/- 0.793 i`

So the three basic solutions are `1.47^n` and `(-0.233 +/-  0.793 i)^n` (approximately).

You did not actually give enough information to find `g`, since we need to know `g(0)`, `g(1)`, and `g(2)`. But for the basic solutions, it's easy to see that `1.47^n = O(1.47^n)` and `(-0.233 +/-  0.793 i)^n = O(1)`, since `|(-0.233 +/-  0.793 i)| < 1`.

Therefore, in almost all cases (except the ones where we can write `g(n) = a (-0.233 + 0.793 i)^n + b (-0.233 -  0.793 i)^n`), we have `g(n)= Theta(1.47^n)` and hence `f(n) = g(n) - c = Theta(1.47^n)`.

Keep in mind that `1.47` is, of course, an approximation. The true value is the unique real solution of `k^3 = k^2 + 1`.